# GHCi can't load script that imports `Data.Set` or `Data.Maybe` if external package is imported

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have a script

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack

{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

module Script where

import qualified Data.Set as Set (Set, fromList)
import           Data.Maybe             (fromJust)
{- import Text.RawString.QQ not neccessary for demonstration -}

main :: IO()
main = print "foo"
```

That I run with `stack --resolver lts-12.5 runghc --package raw-strings-qq Script.hs`

But I can't load it in GHCi:

```
$ stack ghci --resolver lts-12.5 --package raw-strings-qq 

Note: No local targets specified, so a plain ghci will be started with no package hiding or package options.

      If you want to use package hiding and options, then you can try one of the following:

      * If you want to start a different project configuration than /home/t/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml, then you can use stack init to create a new
        stack.yaml for the packages in the current directory. 

      * If you want to use the project configuration at /home/t/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml, then you can add to its 'packages' field.

Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 
GHCi, version 8.4.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/haskell-stack-ghci/2a3bbd58/ghci-script
Prelude> :load Script.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Script           ( Script.hs, interpreted )

Stacko.hs:7:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Set’
    Perhaps you meant Data.Int (from base-4.11.1.0)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
7 | import qualified Data.Set as Set (Set, fromList)
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

### Own research:

I can load the file if I start ghci with just `stack ghci --resolver lts-12.5`.
Interestingly, when I import `Data.Set` 'unqualified' as I do with `Data.Maybe`:

```
import Data.Set
import Data.Maybe
```

the error persists, but when I drop the `Data.Set` import all together I can load `Script.hs`

Imports that don't work: `Data.Set`, `Data.Map.Strict`
Imports that work: `Data.List`, `Data.Function`, `Data.Maybe`
packages that produce the error: `raw-strings-qq`, `HUnit`

Comment: What packages do you have listed under `dependencies` in your `packages.yaml`? It looks to me like you only have `base` there. You will need to add `containers` in order to use `Data.Set` and `Data.Map.Strict`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I don't have additional files, just the one I posted above. But you nugded my in the right direction, starting ghci with `stack ghci --resolver lts-12.5 --package raw-strings-qq containers` works! Since I didn't need to list `containers` for `runghc` I didn't expect to need it for ghci...